# when in reference to spirits what is the meaning? as said in the book of Enoch 39?

Tags: spirit

with the book of Enoch he referrers to calling spirit back like the western people of turtle island when his where abouts was unknown. like Muhammand looking for the goats the book of Enoch 39

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the book of Enoch is not scrpture.

Comment: 1 Enoch is canon in the Ethiopian Orthodox Church. So, I can't agree with voting to close for that reason. If questions about the Gospel of Thomas are considered appropriate for this SE, and it is not considered canon by any Church (correct?), how much more should questions about 1 Enoch be considered appropriate for this SE?

Comment: "Spirit/spirits occurs several times in 1 Enoch 39 - which verse are you thinking about?

Comment: First, let's welcome @Jod.e to the group before shutting his question down. Second, [the Book of Enoch](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/507) is a fairly well established topic on this site as it is apparently quoted in the NT and indeed is accepted as scripture by the Ethiopian Church.  [Pseudepigrapha](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudepigrapha) are also legitimate topics for questions. That said, the question is sorely in need of editing for clarification.

Comment: actually its one of the missing 66 texts ...

Comment: which actually might relate to the Hebrews as it is an unknown source who written it and may fall under the islamic as they pray to the west in the evenings